How to increment range for ARRAYFORMULA function in Google Sheets across different rows
I am trying to create a Split calculator on google sheets for me and my friends whenver we go out to eat for something like Korean food.Sample Split Calculator
I have tried to use ARRAYFORMULA with INDIRECT function to provide a range for these values to be split amongst people with the checkboxes
=ARRAYFORMULA(B2:B12 / COUNTIF(INDIRECT((CHAR(ROWS(1)+ 63 + 3))&SEQUENCE(9,1,2)&":"&(CHAR(ROWS(1)+ 63 + 11))&SEQUENCE(9,1,2)), true))

however, it seems for each iteration of ARRAYFORMULA, it is redoing the SEQUENCE operation so only the first row counts throughout each iteration. Expectation is for each iteration to go B2 / COUNTIF(C2:K2,true), B3 / COUNTIF(C3:K3, true), B4 / COUNTIF(C4:K4, true)... etc
I know I can always just manually plugin these iterations per cell however I want to dynamically do this as in future this would ideally be reused and so the amount of items will change frequently.

Based on your screenshot and your description of what you wanted the arrayformula to do, try this
=BYROW(B2:K12,LAMBDA(q,iferror(INDEX(q,1,1)/COUNTIF(CHOOSECOLS(q,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),"true"))))

BYROW will loop through each row in the provided array and perform an operation defined in the LAMBDA.I assigned the row to a variable named 'q'.
I wrapped the entire formula in an iferror.
The INDEX function is taking the first column of the row, then dividing it by
a count of TRUE values in the subsequent nine columns using CHOOSECOLS.
